# installation doesn't send email

Tags: email

I'm new to Magento and I have just installed my first webshop.

The problem I'm having is that the installations doesn't send out any emails.
Not if an order is made or even when a user doesn't remember his/her password.

The installation is in demo-mode and I have tried to see if the `mail()` function is active on my server, it is (I have send an email).

Comment: Have you set the cron to run?

Comment: ¿Que? I don't think so. I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail settings here http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/store-emails
Also u can install this extension it resolve all email problems
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ebizmarts-magemonkey-official-mailchimp-and-mandrill-extension.html